# How to remove non-ASCII characters?

Tags: python

How can I get rid of characters such as `@ ^  ( )  $` from a string such as the following.

[sample line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IRaJy.png)

Comment: Those are all ASCII characters.

Comment: Those are all asciis Use `regex` to make it happen

Comment: i just realised some of the symbols went missing after i posted it. my main concern is the symbols i am trying to get rid of. Please see the image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the regex meta character `\W` to match all non word characters (everything except a-z, A-Z, 0-9, and _).

For example to replace the non-word characters with space you can:

```
>>> str = "Room+Floor+ST+MARGARETI+?8???$? DDS+SCHOOL,71+ST+ALBANS+RD,+RD,+THOMSON,+3219,+VIC,Australia"
>>> re.sub(r'\W+', ' ', str)
'Room Floor ST MARGARETI 8 DDS SCHOOL 71 ST ALBANS RD RD THOMSON 3219 VIC Australia'
```

You can also be more specific for example, everything that not a word character or a comma:

```
>>> re.sub(r'[^\w\,]+', ' ', str)
'Room Floor ST MARGARETI 8 DDS SCHOOL,71 ST ALBANS RD, RD, THOMSON, 3219, VIC,Australia'
```

Answer (score 0):

First, ASCII has `@ ^ ( ) $`
If you do want to remove @^()$ and other non-alphabetic character, you can use regular expression, by calling `re.sub`

```
import re

x = "Room+Floor+ST+MARGARETI+?8???$??DDS+SCHOOL,71+ST+ALBANS+RD,+RD,+THOMSON,+3219,+VIC,Australia"
regex = re.compile('[^a-zA-Z]')
regex.sub('', x)
# output: RoomFloorSTMARGARETIDDSSCHOOLSTALBANSRDRDTHOMSONVICAustralia
```

Answer (score 0):

The "()@^$" also in ASCII tables.

You can use `re.sub` to replace these characters:

```
import re
re.sub('[@^()$]', '', origin_string)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean removing non alphanumeric chars.
You can refer to the [`ASCII` table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iCOov.gif) and you can do something like this:

```
string = "Room+Floor+ST+MARGARETI+?8???$??DDS+SCHOOL,71+ST+ALBANS+RD,+RD,+THOMSON,+3219,+VIC,Australia"

valid_ranges = [
range(97, 123), # a-z
range(65, 91),  # A-Z
range(48, 58),  # 1-9
]
new_string = ''.join([k for k in string for j in valid_ranges if ord(k) in j])
print(new_string)
```

Output:

```
RoomFloorSTMARGARETI8DDSSCHOOL71STALBANSRDRDTHOMSON3219VICAustralia
```